# mysql foreign key foriegn key relationship

Tags: mysql

Say, myself having three MySQL tables as follows.

1. Table 1 contains table1id, value columns.
2. Table 2 contains table2id, value, table1id (as FK) columns.
3. Table 3 contains table3id, value, table1id (as FK) columns.

Then is the following relationship valid?

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.table1id = t2.table1id
```

Comment: yes it's valid ...what problem you are facing

Comment: Presently No problem.. Asked for information since myself learning mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible.

This one is Joining for teable1 and table2

```
select * from test1 t1 inner join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

This one is joining all three tables,

```
SELECT * FROM test1 t1 
     INNER JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
     INNER JOIN test3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id;
```

Output: [ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e792/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.table1id = t2.table2id 
INNER JOIN table3 t3
ON t1.table1id = t3.table3id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
    WHERE (t1.table1id=t2.table2id) AND (t1.table1id=t3.table3id);
```

** If you want to join only the first 2 tables--Use the code until the `AND`

*** If you want to join all the tables-- Use the entire code.